# Why the click does not work in touch mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

I have made a simple carousal using an online script called "simplyScroll".

here is the link to the script:

http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/#config

My Problem:

here is the link the page:

http://namdarshirazian.com/exhibition.php

Generally in desktop mode, when I click on each image, it runs a javascript and shows a popup. This javascript is written by myself. Simply a simple action of hide and show.

But when viewed with smartphone (android/firefox), it does not triggers click event. VERY STRANGE. Can anyone please help my why this does not work?

The click action is as simple as :

```
$("body").on("click", "element", function(){

});
```

Comment: `click` is only executed when a key on a mouse or similar devices is pressed. It doesn't really make sense on a mobile device - you can't "click" things at all. You either need to use `touchstart` or wrap every image in an `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can experiment with touchup and touchdown events instead. It's actually a right mess caused by people worrying about touches being long. The fastclick library might smooth things out a bit.

Comment: is that an external library?

Comment: Yes. It solves some problems but causes others. I was using it inside phonegap so my experience probably isn't relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem when i did my website responsive for any device resolution, the solution is simple, you write your jQuery as standard but u have to include a script that will allow the jQuery to work on touch devices.

add this script into your website and check the magic result:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/